# Obtaining static JSON data in D3 from Flask app

Tags: python, json, heroku, d3.js, flask

I have a Flask app that I am using to serve a D3 visualization on Heroku. I have the visualization working here: http://wsankey.github.io/dew_mvp/ and the Heroku app here: https://dew.herokuapp.com/. The problem is that I have static json data that is not being picked up by my javascript--there's not even an error being thrown. The map data is 'us.json' and my data is 'dewmvp1.json.'

Here is the relevant piece of the D3 javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Reading map file and data
  queue()
  .defer(d3.json, "/static/us.json")
  .defer(d3.json, "/static/dewmvpv1.json")
  .await(ready);
```

And my app.py file where I thought I might route the data:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
#Main DEW page
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

#About page
@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template("about.html")

#Sending the us.json file
@app.route('/usmap/')
def usmap():
    return "<a href=%s>file</a>" % url_for('static', filename='us.json')

#Sending our data
@app.route('/data/')
def data():
    return "<a href=%s>file</a>" % url_for('static', filename='dewmvp1.json')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And the relevant pieces of the index.html where my script.js is being loaded (to give you an idea of how I'm loading it):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="http://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<link href="{{url_for('static', filename='topojson.v1.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript">
<link href="{{url_for('static', filename='underscore-1.6.0.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript">
<link href="{{url_for('static', filename='jquery-1.10.2.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript">
<link href="{{url_for('static', filename='jquery-ui-1.10.4.js')}}" type="text/javascript">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:400,700|PT+Sans+Caption' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="{{url_for('static', filename='jquery-ui-1.10.4.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="{{url_for('static', filename='grid.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="{{url_for('static', filename='layout.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="{{url_for('static', filename='map.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="{{url_for('static', filename='normalize.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="{{url_for('static', filename='elements.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="{{url_for('static', filename='typography.css')}}">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="{{url_for('static', filename='d3.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript">
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was happening here was that I using  in my index.html when I should have been using . The javascript files were being linked but not executed. @user2569951 was definitely right to say that I needed that {{url_for() }} syntax to access the data but the real issue was more basic. Specifically where I had:

```
<link href="{{url_for('static', filename='d3.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript">
```

I needed instead:

```
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='d3.min.js')}}"></script>
```

That was such a head banger for me but I certainly learned the difference between the tags. This fundamental knowledge is required when managing these files.

Answer (score 0):

in your javascript you need to set your map the following way for it to be accessible.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Reading map file and data
  queue()
  .defer(d3.json, "{{url_for('static', filename='us.json')}}")
  .defer(d3.json, "{{url_for('static', filename='dewmvpv1.json')}}")
  .await(ready)
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment but this isn't doing the trick either. The frustrating part is that it's not throwing an error...there's just nothing happening. I'm wondering if I should just try the AJAX route? I think I'll have to rework my javascript files in that case. Another thread mentioned load order might be the issue for javascript in Flask, but I've tried a few variations. Any other thoughts? Thanks for the comment!

Comment: so this assumes that the `us.json' and `dewmvpv1.json` are sitting in the root of the static folder  (i.e. `static/us.json` and not `static/maps/us.json`).  if they are not then add `<foldername>/us.json`.  the route to the file must be specified.  can you list your directory structure for the files?

Comment: Yep, it wasn't the file structure but something much more basic. Wish I could upvote you but I don't have the reputation yet. Thanks for the help.

Comment: yes, i see it now.  i focused on the queue function when i should have looked at your load syntax first!  glad you got it figured out.